# How to align center navbar with only bootstrap 4.5.3?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble centering my content in the bootstrap nav-bar. I'm using bootstrap 4. I've read many posts, but the bootstrap 4 or methods used will not work with my code! I'm really frustrated, so this is like my last noption. Any help would be appreciated!

```
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the children of the `nav` tag in a `div` with classes: `mx-auto and d-flex` to achieve a fully centred navbar.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="mx-auto d-flex">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

See [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/4L7u1HEQnt)

Comment: Thanks , Why did not working navbar-toggler, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723185/bootstrap-4-5-3-navbar-toggle-is-not-working